Navigating to a dynamic route based on ID from a table in Blazor
I have a table in a Blazor page that displays several records. Each row contains an ID, and I want to allow users to click on the ID, which should navigate to a new page with a dynamic route based on that ID.
For example, when I’m on /page1 and I click an ID (e.g., ABC1), I want to navigate to /page2/ABC1.
How can I implement this kind of dynamic routing in Blazor?
I'm using .Net8 and server-side rendermode.

You could try this sample
Home.razor
@page "/"
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Links</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in list)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><a  href="Page2/@item">@item </a> </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
@code {
    private List<string> list = new List<string> { "ABC1", "DEF2" };
}

Page2.razor
@page "/page2/{ID}"
<h3>Page2</h3>
@ID
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}


As per MS-docs (check here)
@page "/route-parameter-1/{text}"

<PageTitle>Route Parameter 1</PageTitle>

<h1>Route Parameter Example 1</h1>

<p>Blazor is @Text!</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Text { get; set; }
}

